# Best Practices to apply a function by group on dask

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I have a large dataset stored on hdf5 file, and I need to perform some operations.

```
    sku   cente units
0   103896  1   2.0
1   103896  1   0.0
2   103896  1   5.0
3   103896  1   0.0
4   103896  1   7.0
```

Using dask, I can perform statistical operations quite fast. This operation takes less than 30s:

```
df.groupby(['center', 'sku'])['units'].agg([np.mean]).compute()
```

And if I visualize the DAGs, everything seems well organized:

[image]

However, if I try to apply a function:

```
def days_no_sell(x):
    return x.eq(0).sum()/((x.eq(0)&x.shift().ne(0)).sum())
```

Using Groupby with `.apply`:

```
 df \
.groupby(['center', 'sku'])['units'] \
.apply(days_no_sell, meta=pd.Series(dtype=float, name='days_no_sell'))
```

It takes around 13 minutes, and the DAGs are much more complicated than I would’ve expected.

[image]

It seems this is actually because data shuffling behind the scene.

Do you guys have some suggestion to perform this operation efficiently using dask ?

I have tried to use first both `.repartition(npartitions=15)` and `.set_index()`, but it doesn't performed better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groupby-apply operations with custom functions are genuinely difficult to do in parallel.  You need to move all of the data for each group to a single task to run your custom function.  Because Dask does not know what your function does, it can not be clever here.

If you can fit all of your data in RAM then just use Pandas.

If you can think a little bit about how to perform your operation in parallel then you might consider constructing a custom aggregation.  https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#custom-aggregation

Comment: Using this examples, that calculates the mean of days without selling ´x.eq(0).sum()/((x.eq(0)&x.shift().ne(0)).sum())´, I am a bit confused on chunck argument from aggregation function.